# Is this possible with a pageswitch?

Tags: php, url, if-statement, include

Usually i would use url parameters for a pageswitch,

lets say i got this switch
so p is the page

```
if(isset($_GET['p']){
    $page = $_GET['p'];
    if(file_exists('includes/' . $page . '.php')){
        // include the page
    } else {
        // include error page
    }
} else {
    // include homepage
}
```

my url would look like this:

http://www.example.com?p=contact

is it possible to have a pageswitch with an url like this:

http://www.example.com/contact

mention the missing .php at the end of the url.

and can someone tell me if this php if else statement is a proper way to include files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible to have a page switch with a page such as http://www.example.com/contact.

You will need to re-write traffic however, so if you have access to a .htacess file you can add something like this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^/(.+)/?$ http://www.example.com?p=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This way the user can navigate to /contact and it will re-direct to ?p=contact

If you've got lots of pages may I suggest using a switch statement to check your $_GET?

A switch statement in your case might look like this...

```
if(isset($_GET['p'])){
   $page = $_GET['p'];
   switch($page){

     case 'contact':
       if(file_exists('includes/' . $page . '.php')){
          // include the page
      } else {
          // include error page
      }
      break; 

   }
}else{

}
```

Hope this helps